# Touching pig or dog on screen

Tags: waswasa

I am having really bad thoughts recently about touching a pig or a dog on screen. It sounds really weird and confusing as to why I am thinking this but sometimes i am watching videos on my ipad and my hands are wet and a ad or a video comes up with a pig or a dog. Will my hands be considered impure and will i have to wash my hands seven times and once with dust or dirt?

Answer (score -1):

Seriously!!!!!!!!!
Who ever said that touching any animal on screen making you impure?
Any references!!?

That's not correct.
Islam is a logical religion.

Comment: THANK U SO MUCH!! IDK WHY I THOUGHT I WAS IMPURE AND I WAS TOO EMBARASSED TO ASK ASWELL

Comment: You are most welcome. It's better to ask, if you ask once, you will learn. But, if you don’t ask you never learn. Thanks!

Comment: The purpose of SE sites is to maintain good quality questions and answers. Please edit your answer tone to a more serious one.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/63060)